# Not able to generate Rules list by using Apriori Algorithm

Tags: python-2.7, associations, data-mining, data-analysis, apriori

I want to see the Association Rules within my dataset which contributes to each Gene Type but I am facing trouble please check the output in the images attached. I want to know what am I doing wrong any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

This is the command I am using : 
from apyori import apriori

```
rules = list(apriori(genes))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like the default output of the `str` function ofnthe `frozenset` class, then you need to implement your own serialization to text.

It's straightforward.

Comment: Okay I thought its because some columns have multiple values in the some rows

Comment: I am finding hard to understand the Rules this way can you refer me any link or explain me more about it?

Comment: The set is the frequent itemset. The rules are supposedly in the ordered statistics object. But from a quick look, that package's implementation seems to be *really* inefficient anyway (and there are many really bad packages!). Rather use pyFIM instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will check pyFIM for sure

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar to below code to display the content:

`final_result = []
 for i in range (0,len(rules)):
    a = []
    for k in range(0,3):
        a.append(str(results[i][k]))
    final_result.append(a)`